# Swift with core data

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsnumber

i am just starting out with swift and core data. I have an entity invoiceList and created some attributes (some strings, integer 32 and decimal).

I created an edit/add viewcontroller, but now i am stuck with the add newItem part. I am getting the error "cannot assign a value of type string? to a value of type NSNumber?"

I have tried different ways to cast vat textfield as Int but without success.

I tried

```
    var invoiceVATString = nItem.valueForkey("invoiceVAT") as String
    invoiceVATString = vat.text
```

here the newItem func

```
func newItem(){
    let context = self.context
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("invoiceList", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let nItem = InvoicesList(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    nItem.invoiceShopName = shopName.text
    nItem.invoiceDescr = productDescription.text
    nItem.invoiceVAT = vat.text<-cannot assign a value of type string? to a value of type NSNumber?
    nItem.invoiceNumber = orderNumber.text<-cannot assign a value of type string? to a value of type NSNumber?

}
```

Now i know invoiceVAT is a core data attribute with type decimal and vat is a textfield. How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you want `invoiceVAT` as a numeric value or as a string? Some VAT numbers contain letters, btw.

Comment: For invoiceVAT i want only numbers and a period. 

FYI: I guess i have named it wrong, i meant the bruto and netto difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example of using a number formatter to retrieve an NSNumber from a String

```
let aNumberString = "1235.45"

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()

if let theNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString(aNumberString) {

println(theNumber)
}
```

Comment: the errors are gone ;). Is this the way to show an integer in a textfield and how do i handle attributes with type date? does something like NSDateFormatter exists?

Comment: There sure is, and string interoperation makes going to a String as easy as "\variableNameHere"

Comment: within func newItem i get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" i have comment out all nItem variable except for the shopName but still i get the message. Do you see where i am going wrong?

Comment: NSDecimalFormatter doesn't seem to exists, i updated by "Create NSManagedObject Subclass…" from the Core Data editor menu and the decimal are now giving errors 
Cannot assign a value of type 'NSNumber?' to a value of type 'NSDecimalNumber?'

Comment: Actually you can use NSDecimalNumber which has a String initializer NSDecimalNumber(string: "123.5") - this can return the string "not a number" so you need to check for that!